# How to let a parent class know about a change in its children?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, parent-child, inotifypropertychanged

This is an example code:

```
public class MyParent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<MyChild> MyChildren;

    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var child in MyChildren)
            {
                if (child.IsChanged) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

public class MyChild : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Value;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Value == value)
                return;
            _Value = value;
            RaiseChanged("Value");
            RaiseChanged("IsChanged");
        }
    }
    private int _DefaultValue;
    public int DefaultValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _DefaultValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_DefaultValue == value)
                return;
            _DefaultValue = value;
            RaiseChanged("DefaultValue");
            RaiseChanged("IsChanged");
        }
    }

    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return (Value != DefaultValue);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Let's say I now have two instances of my classes, one as myParent, and the other as myChild.
I have two visual elements, that each have a property bound to the IsChnaged property of my instances; ElementA bound to myParent.IsChanged and ElementB bound to myChild.IsChanged.

When myChild.Value differs from its default value, the myChild.IsChanged is set to true and the ElementB is updated accordingly.

What I need is when either of the myParent children (which here is only one) have their IsChanged value set to true, its own (the parent's) IsChanged value be set to true and its corresponding 
element (ElementA here) be updated accordingly.

The myParent.IsChanged is only read once (when the binding is set) and it has no sense about its children changing. Where should i put the RaiseChanged("IsChanged") for MyParent? How can I let the parent know when its children have changed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could make your child constructor take as parameter the parent object, and while creating those child objects you could give the parent object in the constructor.

Comment: That is something I like to avoid, I'd rather not introduce the parent to the child, either in the constructor or even as a property. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`INotifyPropertyChanged` has already provided the mechanism for you: the `PropertyChanged` event. Just have the parent add a handler to its children's `PropertyChanged`, and then in that handler call `RaiseChanged("IsChanged");`

Also, you may want to put the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation in a base class, and have your (what appear to be) ViewModels inherit from that. Not required for this option, of course, but it will make the code a little cleaner.

**Update:** In the parent object:

```
// This list tracks the handlers, so you can
// remove them if you're no longer interested in receiving notifications.
//  It can be ommitted if you prefer.
List<EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>> changedHandlers =
    new List<EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>>();

// Call this method to add children to the parent
public void AddChild(MyChild newChild)
{
    // Omitted: error checking, and ensuring newChild isn't already in the list
    this.MyChildren.Add(newChild);
    EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> eh =
        new EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(ChildChanged);
    newChild.PropertyChanged += eh;
    this.changedHandlers.Add(eh);
}

public void ChildChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyChild child = sender as MyChild;
    if (this.MyChildren.Contains(child))
    {
        RaiseChanged("IsChanged");
    }
}
```

You don't actually have to add anything to the child class, since it is already raising the correct event when it changes.

Comment: can you help me with an example?

Comment: I have this error:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>' to 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler'"

Comment: @iXed Sorry about that; didn't have a chance to compile and test. You can just declare the handlers as `PropertyChangeEventHandler` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked pretty well, but there is one problem, I'd like to save my objects using serializing, but when i open them, the opened objects no longer have the PropertyChanged handler set to them. Any solution to that?
BTW, may I edit your answer so there would be no confusion for others?

Answer (score 4):

Doing this kind of communication can be tricky, especially if you want to avoid memory leaks due to the event handlers that you hook up. There is also the case of handling items that are added / removed from the collection.

I've really enjoyed the power and simplicity of the [Continuous LINQ project](http://clinq.codeplex.com/) on codeplex. It has some very rich features for setting up "Reactive Objects", "Continuous Values", and "Continuous Collections". These let you define your criteria as a Linq expression and then let the CLINQ library keep the underlying values up to date in real time.

In your case, you could set up the parent with a ContinuousFirstOrDefault() linq query that watched for any child where "IsChanged == true". As soon as a child sets the value to true and raises PropertyChanged, the continuous value will detect the change and raise a corresponding PropertyChanged in the parent.

The benefits:

1. Weak references and weak events are used to prevent the event handlers in the parent from locking the child in memory. It can get very messy to add / remove these handlers from all the children.
2. You can declare the dependency in the parent without need to make special changes in the child or make the child aware of the parent. Rather, the child just needs to properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged. This puts the "logic" close to the object that cares, rather than spreading event craziness and inter-dependencies all over the code.

Here's what the code might look like:

```
public class MyParent : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<MyChild> _MyChildren;
    private ContinuousValue<MyChild> _ContinuousIsChanged = null;

    public MyParent()
    {
        _MyChildren = new ObservableCollection<MyChild>();

        // Creat the ContinuousFirstOrDefault to watch the MyChildren collection.
        // This will monitor for newly added instances, 
        // as well as changes to the "IsChanged" property on 
        // instances already in the collection.
        _ContinuousIsChanged = MyChildren.ContinuousFirstOrDefault(child => child.IsChanged);
        _ContinuousIsChanged.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => RaiseChanged("IsChanged");
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyChild> MyChildren
    {
        get { return _MyChildren; }
    }

    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get
        {
            // If there is at least one child that matches the 
            // above expression, then something has changed.
            if (_ContinuousIsChanged.Value != null)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

public class MyChild : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Value;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Value == value)
                return;
            _Value = value;
            RaiseChanged("Value");
            RaiseChanged("IsChanged");
        }
    }
    private int _DefaultValue;
    public int DefaultValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _DefaultValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_DefaultValue == value)
                return;
            _DefaultValue = value;
            RaiseChanged("DefaultValue");
            RaiseChanged("IsChanged");
        }
    }

    public bool IsChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return (Value != DefaultValue);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaiseChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

The above code sets up the ContinuousFirstOrDefault in the constructor so that it is always monitoring. However, in some cases you can optimize this by lazily instantiating the ContinuousFirstOrDefault only when the getter for "IsChanged" is called. That way you don't start monitoring for changes until you know that some other piece of code actually cares.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify things for yourself by storing your children in an `ItemObservableCollection<T>`, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849361/itempropertychanged-not-working-on-observablecollection-why). That would allow you to do this:

```
private ItemObservableCollection<MyChild> children;

public MyParent()
{
    this.children = new ItemObservableCollection<MyChild>();
    this.children.ItemPropertyChanged += delegate(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Equals("IsChanged", e.PropertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsChanged");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: ItemObservableCollection? or ObservableCollection?
and i'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: nice solution, but still not that simple

Answer (score 0):

Something I do not see in your code sample provide is an actually reference of parent to child. It is not enough to simply have interface to communicate through, but you must also create the reference. Something like `myChild.parent = this;` followed by the binding of the event handlers across the channel, in the "parent" property of the child object it would look like:

```
public INotifyPropertyChanged parent
{
   get{return _parent;}
   set
   {
      _parent = value;
      this.PropertyChanged += _parent.RaiseChanged();
   }
}
```

I don't have enough context to perfect this code for you but this should move you in the right direction.

Comment: That is something I'd like to avoid, I'd rather not introduce the parent to the child, either in the constructor or even as a property. But I'm kinda getting to believe I'm not right.