# WPF - event bubbling from child ViewModel to Parent View Model

Tags: wpf, event-bubbling

I have a user control (`AddNewProductRowView`), which has a few basic elements like text box dropdown etc. I am binding that UserControl with a ViewModel - `AddNewProductRowViewModel`. I then have a MainWindow which has a ListBox, the itemsource of which is a List of the above mentioned userControl (`AddNewProductRowViewModelList`). The MainWindow binds to a DataModel - `AddNewProductViewModel`.  The AddNewProductViewModel contains the Property `AddNewProductRowViewModelList` to which I add the user control dynamically. And I also wire the Property change event then as -

```
AddNewProductRowViewModelList = new ObservableCollection<AddNewProductRowViewModel>();
        AddNewProductRowViewModel objAddNewProductRowViewModel;
        for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
        {
            objAddNewProductRowViewModel = new AddNewProductRowViewModel();
            AddNewProductRowViewModelList.Add(objAddNewProductRowViewModel);
            objAddNewProductRowViewModel.PropertyChanged += delegate(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (string.Equals("ProductNo", e.PropertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductNo"));
                }
            };
        }
```

Here `ProductNo` is one of the the Properties bound to userControl in `AddNewProductRowViewModel`.  Both models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The Control renders as expected and when I change the textBox for Product No, the `OnPropertyChanged` for Child, ie in `AddNewProductRowViewModel` fires , but the same is not trapped in the Parent ViewModel.

Please advise as to what I am doing wrong. Fact is that I did the same for a DropDownList - for list of states State, and wired the event exactly the same way. That works just fine... :(.

The only difference I see here is that now I am using a User Control.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I then edited the code as per - [Kent Boogaart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849361/itempropertychanged-not-working-on-observablecollection-why)

```
AddNewProductRowViewModelList = new ItemObservableCollection<AddNewProductRowViewModel>();
 AddNewProductRowViewModelList.CollectionChanged += OnAddNewProductViewModelListChanged;

 AddNewProductRowViewModel objAddNewProductRowViewModel;
 for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++)
 {
    objAddNewProductRowViewModel = new AddNewProductRowViewModel();
    AddNewProductRowViewModelList.Add(objAddNewProductRowViewModel);
 }
 AddNewProductRowViewModelList.ItemPropertyChanged += OnAddNewProductRowViewModelItemChanged;
```

Added these two methods -

```
void OnAddNewProductViewModelListChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {

 }

 void OnAddNewProductRowViewModelItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

The first one is called when I add items...the second one is not when I update ProductNo.

**SOLUTION** : After so much of banging my head..I realised this...

In the `AddNewProductRowView` class , inside the constructor...

```
public partial class AddNewProductRowView : UserControl
    {
        public AddNewProductRowViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

        public AddNewProductRowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new AddNewProductRowViewModel();
            DataContext = ViewModel;
        }
    }
```

Now..I am assigning the `DataContext` a new `ViewModel` and hence I was losing the bindings that I attached in the parent.

My Bad...   I hope this question helps somebody to clear his / her concepts.

Thanks all who took interest.

**CASE CLOSED !!**

Comment: you have listened to propertychanged for all the child VMs i.e all the AddNewProductRowViewModel in parent? if yes, can you share how are you doing it?

Comment: @nit- not all but the property in consideration - ProductNo - and as I mentioned above, the event gets raised in the child OnPropertyChanged - I verified with a  breakpoint. If you still need the code I can post. (I hope thats what you are asking)

Comment: no @Saket i am asking have u listened the propertychanged  for all the instances of child VMs?

Comment: yes - in a loop . The Above Code of adding to list and attaching is in a loop. Did I understand right ?

Comment: so you are saying the code never comes inside the delegate listener you shared?

Comment: Exactly..In fact I did similar approach for a dropdown and it works

Comment: this is weird... just a suggestion can you test your code by creating the function listener in your parent vm and attach the same function to property change of all the child vms... lets see if it gets called

Comment: Umm - I am not sure how you are asking. Can you guide please.