# ListBox bind to ObservableCollection is not updated with collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I have next model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyList {get; set;}
}

public class MyObject
{
   MyObservableDictionary MyDictionary {get; set;}
}

public class  MyObservableDictionary : ObservableCollection<EnymValue>
{
}

public class EnymValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private MyEnum key;
    private string value;

    public MyEnum Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this.key;
        }
        set
        {
            this.key = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Key");
        }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public LanguageValue(MyEnum key, string value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
}
```

And on View I have a ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList, Mode=OneWay}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyDictionary, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myEnumToTextConverter}}" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

(myEnumToTextConverter converter is just selects first element from collection and return it's value, or some specified constant if collection is null or empty)

**I want my Model's list box to be updated on view, when any `EnymValue` values are changed.
Is it possible somehow to implement this?**

Currently the view is not updated when `Value` changed.
I've tried to inherit `EnymValue` from `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but this didn't helped. Looks like `PropertyChanged == null` on `EnymValue.NotifyPropertyChanged` when property updated.

Comment: Not the way you're doing it. That `Binding` isn't going to subscribe to `INotifyCollectionChanged` because you're binding the collection to a `String` property. So when you alter the collection, nobody will hear about it and the binding won't update the target.

Answer (score 2):

`ObservableCollection` is able to notify UI about changes when collection itself is changed(elemends are added or deleted). But `ObservableCollection` is not aware of changes that are happening when you modify one of it's items. To solve the problem you may subscribe to `CollectionChange` event of observable collection, and when new item is added, subscribe to new items's PropertyChanged. When PropertyChanged event is raised, you can trigger notification on your list `OnPropertyChanged(()=>MyItems);` You should be careful implementing this solution and remember to unsubscribe from the event's to avoid memory leaks.

An example of what I mean you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3849454/5246145).

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've just tested proposed solution and it works as I expected. I mean OnPropertyChanged("MyItems") is not ignored like you mentioned. If needed I can provide code to prove it. Why do you think it should be ignored?

Comment: I was quite sure I'd tried that and it hadn't worked. I've been wrong before though.

Comment: Just tested it and you're right, it works as you say. Thanks for calling my attention to that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyDictionary` should force a refresh. Easiest way is to re-assign its old value, and implement INPC in MyObject like below :

```
public class MyObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        MyObservableDictionary _myDictionary;
        public MyObservableDictionary MyDictionary {
            get
            {
                return _myDictionary;
            }
            set
            {
                _myDictionary = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyDictionary");
            }
        }

        public MyObject()
        {
            MyDictionary = new MyObservableDictionary();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

Sample code to change Value :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // vm is ViewModel instance, vm is DataContext set for Window

    var old = vm.MyList[0].MyDictionary;
    vm.MyList[0].MyDictionary[0].Value = "aaaa";
    vm.MyList[0].MyDictionary = old;
}
```

I tested this, and it displays changed value as "aaaa".